# Redux Toolkit Query and TypeScript: How to implement transformResponse

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit Query and I am trying to implement `transformResponse`

```
...
    getPosts: builder.query<PostsResponse[], void>({
        query: () => GET_POSTS,                       
        transformResponse: (response: PostsResponse[], meta, arg): Posts[] => {
            return converPostsForUi(response)
        }
    }),
...
```

However, I am getting:

```
Type 'Posts[]' is not assignable to type 'PostsResponse[] | Promise<PostsResponse[]>'.     
Type 'Posts[]' is not assignable to type 'PostsResponse[]'. 
Type 'Posts' is missing the following properties from type 'PostsResponse': id, created, updated, version, and 4 more.  
endpointDefinitions.d.ts(53, 5): The expected type comes from property 'transformResponse' which is declared here on type 'Omit<EndpointDefinitionWithQuery<void, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, PostsResponse[]> & { ...; } & { ...; } & QueryExtraOptions<...>, "type"> | Omit<...>'
```

What is the compiler trying to tell me?

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Seems pretty clear - it tells you Posts isn't PostsResponse, because it's missing properties.  You're transforming the response to something that _isn't_ what you said the query result would be.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm... If I do it like this `const response = await fetch(GET_POSTS);
const postResponse: PostsResponse[] = await response.json();
const convertedPosts = converPostsForUi(postResponse)` it works...

Comment: @jonrsharpe especially: The compiler tells me this before I run the app... It gets highlighted in the code. It feels like I am missunderstand the syntax, how to pass the types? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-basequery

Comment: @jonrsharpe and I can confirm that the error occurs when I add the return type `Posts[]` to  `transformResponse`. When I make the type `any` it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type in `builder.query(<RETURNTYPE>, void)` to the return type of the `transformResponse()` function

```
...
    getPosts: builder.query<Posts[], void>({
                              ^
     This type must match the return type in transformResponse()
        query: () => GET_POSTS,                       
        transformResponse: (response: PostsResponse[], meta, arg): Posts[] => {
            return converPostsForUi(response)
        }
    }),
...
```

Comment: This highlights a good point. i'm facing the same issue with `queryFn`. But your workaround won't help me. Looks like `transformResponse` is intended only for using `query` and `baseQuery`. If you're using `queryFn` just transform the response directly within your function